# Need syntax help to specialize class methods based on type of template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I have a generic thread-safe queue class that uses `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>` as the container type (as specified through the template args). However, I would like to alternatively specialize this to use a simpler `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.  Unfortunately this would mean using a different technique to retrieve the top-most element of the queue (`top()` for `std::priority_queue<T>` or `front()` for `std::queue<T>`).  I have a **[live coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/758697f9f3c618fe)** that shows a working prototype for `priority_queue` types. However, if I attempt to use the `std::queue` by adding the following code:

I get the expected error from the compiler indicating that `std::queue` has no `top()` method.

I suspect that the key to getting this right is to use `std::enable_if_t<T>` for each of the `wait_and_pop` methods. How would I do this?

**EDIT**:  Thanks to T.C's suggestion, I believe that the generic solution that works for both GCC and MSVC requires the following adjustment to the **UtlThreadSafeQueue**.  There is an updated live [coliru demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8eba990af38e6113):

```
// Note that overloading 2 function using expression SFINAE
// as shown here does not work on MSVC compiler - it does
// work on later builds of GCC though.
//template<class Q>
//auto front_or_top(Q& q) -> decltype(q.front()) {
//    return q.front();
//}
//template<class Q>
//auto front_or_top(Q& q) -> decltype(q.top()) {
//    return q.top();
//}

// this is a specific overload to work around the missing
// expression SFINAE in MSVC - for the std::queue<T>
template<class T>
auto front_or_top(std::queue<T>& q) -> decltype(q.front()) {
    return q.front();
}

// this is a specific overload to work around the missing
// expression SFINAE in MSVC - for the std::priority_queue<T>
template<class T>
auto front_or_top(std::priority_queue<T>& q) -> decltype(q.top()) {
    return q.top();
}

/**
 * default type of container is a std::queue - which by default
 * uses a std::deque<> of std::shared_ptr<T>'s. The default
 * std::queue<T> does not need to order elements, and as
 * such, it does not require an element comparator as is
 * required by its priority queue counterpart.
 *
 * For the UtlThreadSafeQueue variant that uses a priority
 * queue, we must define a comparator to compare
 * <code>std::shared_ptr<T>'s</code>.
 *
 * To use a UtlThreadSafeQueue with a priority_queue container,
 * use as follows:
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 * // using priority queue
 * UtlThreadSafeQueue<PriorityLevel, std::priority_queue<
 *     std::shared_ptr<PriorityLevel>,
 *     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<PriorityLevel>>,
 *     ptr_less<std::shared_ptr<PriorityLevel>>>> prtyQ;
 *
 * }</pre>
 */
template<typename T, typename Cont = std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>>
class UtlThreadSafeQueue {
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    Cont data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::atomic<bool> shutdownFlag;
public:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an overloaded free function helper. One possible way:

```
template<class Q>
auto front_or_top(Q& q) -> decltype(q.front()) { return q.front(); }

template<class Q>
auto front_or_top(Q& q) -> decltype(q.top()) { return q.top(); }
```

And then do `front_or_top(cont)`. Note that this is ambiguous if the container defines both `front()` and `top()`.

Alternatively, you can also overload `front_or_top` just for `queue`s and `priority_queue`s:

```
template<class T, class Cont>
auto front_or_top(std::queue<T, Cont>& q) -> decltype(q.front()) { return q.front(); }

template<class T, class Cont, class Comp>
auto front_or_top(std::priority_queue<T, Cont, Comp>& q) -> decltype(q.top()) { return q.top(); }
```

Comment: i'm relatively new to meta-programming, how does this work under the covers?  is it using some sort of SFINAE to match whether front_or_top?  Don't the q.front() and q.top() have the same decltype? - not sure how the compiler resolves this, also when I added this to to my demo, it still returns the same error

Comment: @johnco3, it is true that the return type of `q.top()` and `q.front()` are the same, but that's not important. The signature of a method includes the type of the parameters and the type of the return. Here, the return type is specified as `decltype(q.front())`. If the type of `q` (i.e. `Q`) doesn't have a method `front()`, then this function doesn't have a well-defined return type and therefore it is ignored via SFINAE. Further, if you wanted to test for the *presence* of method `foo`, but actually return from method `bar`, you could do the return type as `decltype(0, q.foo(), q.bar())`.

Comment: I updated the code on Coliru, and it seems like it works on GCC using T.C's free function suggestion, however for some reason, Visual C++ 2013 complains indicating 'unknown-type front_or_top(Q &)' : function template has already been defined.  The updated coliru code can be seen at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d964c8219c921cc4 - the code is identical to that in coliru with the normal #ifndef header guards

Comment: @johnco3 If you need it to work on MSVC, overload on `priority_queue`/`queue` instead. This code depends on expression SFINAE, which MSVC doesn't yet support.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that TC, if you can edit your answer with that detail I'l test it out and mark your answer as the accepted answer

Comment: @T.C. Is the edited code above what you had in mind when you indicated that I should overload on priority_queue/queue?

Comment: @T.C. thanks your solution is much better than mine as you also templatized the container type and in the case of the priority queue, the comparator, nice one